# New version of Matlab (R2017a), won't open video files (.avi) that my old version (R2014a) can run fine

Tags: matlab, video, video-codecs

I'm using VideoReader as follows:

> > video_object=VideoReader('filename.avi');

This runs totally fine on R2014a, but the same code, for the same video files and on the same operating system, returns the following error in R2017a:

Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
The file does not appear to have any video data.

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);

The video files I'm trying to open are encoded with the codec 'Microsoft video 1'. A random other video file, namely 'rhinos.avi', seems to open just fine.

This is on Mac (Sierra).

It seems a very strange problem to me. Is it maybe possible that certain video codecs were removed form the new version of Matlab? I've been unable to find information about this. Maybe other have had the same problem? Is it possible to install codecs manually?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When upgrading Matlab, always check out the [release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html). This issue appears to be detailed under "R2017a > Data Import and Export > Functionality being removed or changed." The ["Microsoft video 1" codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Video_1) is an ancient codec developed back in 1992.

Comment: Thanks, this must be it. I will convert the files manually.